# Запись файла и ретрансляция потока - FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Всем привет. Пишу простой видеосервер. Задача - получение аудио-видео потока от камер (RTP пакеты), запись видеофайлов (*.MP4) и одновременно трансляция на фронт живого видео с конкретно выбраной камеры. Первая часть - работа с камерой, буферизация RTP пакетов, работает. Как сконфигурировать ffmpeg, что бы я могу ему скармливать RTP поток из буфера, он писал файл и одновременно вел трансляция? Если такое вообще возможно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если совсем кратко, `ffmpeg -i [поток-камеры] -c copy -f segment -segment_time 60 сегмент%05d.mp4 -c copy -f hls трансляция-для-фронта/playlist.m3u8`

Comment: привет, спасибо. А если более подробно?)) например, поток с камеры, у меня данные от камеры лежат в буфере, как содержимое буфера отдать ffmpeg?

Comment: А зачем вам буфер? Почему бы не брать поток с камеры напрямую?

Comment: камера 4G, передает поток не RTSP, а RTP по UDP для минимизации задержки. У нас есть механизм, который проверяет все ли пакеты пришли, и если какие то потерялись, то камера их отправит еще раз. Соответственно в буфере RTP пакеты упорядочиваются - выстраиваются по порядку и далее должны передаваться в ffmpeg.

Comment: ffmpeg [поддерживает приём rtp-пакетов по udp](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtp), можно наверное попытаться слать их из буфера, но вероятно подадобится использовать sdp-файл, содержащий описание rtp-потоков, что-то вроде такого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682917